# How to write click event for Listpreference from Preference activity?

Tags: android

I created Preference activity. It contains two ListPreferences. How to write Onclick() for the Listpreference view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to monitor the preferences changes in SharedPreferences using an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Name", 0);
    sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                String key) {
            //do whatever
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your looking for `pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(onPreferenceClickListener);`

Or more likely `setOnPreferenceChangeListener`

You can find out how it works here;
[onPreferenceClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceClickListener%28android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener%29)

Have a look at the following tutorial, should help you out;
http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/android-preferenceactivity.html

Comment: Thanks you!! please tell me any example!