# Executing code after a preference has been changed

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I know that I can get a [`Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) if I want to execute some code *before* the preference gets changed in the `SharedPreferences`.

I'm writing an application that fetches some text from the internet. It can do that in multiple languages, and the user selects using a `Preference` which language he wants to see. When the data is changed, I need to fetch the text again using the new language.

To fetch this text I'm using a static method which does not take the language as a parameter (it gets it itself using the `SharedPreferences`). That means that calling this method from the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` will not help me, because at that point the preference isn't saved yet.

Is there a different listener I can use to execute code *after* the preference has been changed? Or should I just add code to commit the change to the `SharedPreferences` myself, manually, in the listener?

Comment: Change the `SharedPreferences` when user changes the language and then call your static method. Now when do you have to do that, depends on how to you fetch the user's action.

Comment: What do you mean by "the user selects using a Preference which language he wants to see" ?

Comment: You can override `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` in `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13563870/3498044

Comment: However, solution pointed out by @Ryan ( `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` on a SharedPreference object) is different from the preference listener you were talking about in your question, and has a promising past tense in it. Did you check it out?

Comment: @miav thanks for making me pay attention to that, I thought it was something I already looked into. Perhaps we can clean up these comments, they are not useful to others.

Comment: Did it work? So I'll post an answer

Comment: @Ryan yes, it did, thanks a lot. Please add an answer. And after that we can clean up these comments, I'll start with mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method in `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` and call the static method there. It gets called after the preferences have been saved.

Use it this way:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            // Do your stuff
      }
});
```